# How do I include a variable in an FQL query?

Tags: ruby, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, koala

I would like to use a variable in my FQL query. I'm using Koala in my rails environment to access Facebook variables

```
u1 = f["uid1"]
@opponent = @graph.fql_query('select name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid = "' + u1 + '"')
```

The above code is not working. I'd appreciate any feedback! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this on IRB and it works just fine. Make sure you have the right facebook token and UID. Just fetch "me" by saying @graph.get_object('me') on your console to confirm if the facebook token is right. Also, try printing value of u1 if it is right in your case.

```
@graph Koala::Facebook::RestAPI.new(<fb_token>)
uid = <some uid>
@opponent = @graph.fql_query('select name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid = "' + uid + '"')
```

Comment: Thanks @Divya for your help. The problem was the wrong FB token. You are exactly right!

Comment: @ddb : suppose i have an array of user_id's (ex: u_id = [1,2,3]) Now how can I use this array in fql_query??